# Logit: Check whether a regressor is more useful for forecasting variable A or variable B

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, forecasting, predictive-models

I'm running a logit regression where I'm regressing dependent variable A on a regressor X, and then a separate regression of a regressor B on X. So A and B are simply a different streaks of 0s and 1s.
I'd like to be able to make a qualitative statement about X: e.g. X is more/less useful for predicting A  than it is for predicting B, or they are about the same (the difference is not statistically significant).

To eyeball the difference, one could look at marginal probabilities, area under the ROC curve, <s>R squared</s>... But what would be the way to compare whether the difference across the models with different dependent variables is meaningful?

Comment: likelihood ratio test would be one possibility

Comment: Isn't it usually used on nested models only (e.g. to test parameter restrictions)? That wouldn't apply here.

Comment: I meant compare both models to the respective model. Reading your question again, if you are interested in the predictive power, the AUC would be more interesting of course